# Python: dynamically store access for dictionary

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary, reference

I've tried to find out how to do this (google, SO, etc), but I'm probably using the wrong keywords...

Basically I'm looping over a file line by line, and if I hit a keyword, I want to add it into a dictionary as its key, however, I want to add its value as a dictionary of the initial dictionary, and then any following hits as a child to it (and so on) unless I hit a close character, where it will go up one level in the dictionary.

example file:

```
def myitem {
    def aSubItem {
        abc
    }
    def anotherSubItem {
        hi!
        hows you?
    }
}
```

so I'd get a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {
    "myitem" : {
        "aSubItem" : { "abc" },
        "anotherSubItem" : { "hi!", "hows you?" }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm looking at some way I can store the current depth (or dict access), so like, you'd access 'abc' by doing mydict['myitem']['aSubItem'], but I want to be able to store how deep I am incase someone adds something to that block... so something like:

```
curLevel = ['myitem']['aSubItem']
```

then I Could tell mydict to access the curLevel, then when the block has finished (hits a } ), I could tell it to go up 'one level' to

```
curLevel = ['myitem']
```

## ===================

I know that I could use

```
curLevel = mydict
```

which would let me access myDic using curLevel...
That works fine going down into the dictionary levels...

however, how would I go up one?
i.e. if I had:

```
curLevel = mydict['myitem']['aSubItem']
```

how would I go to

```
curLevel = mydict['myitem']
```

====================

Here is some sample code, cause everyone likes sample code :P

This is working going down into the dictionary, I'm just not sure how to make it go back up

```
import os
import re

# file location
fle = "myfilelocation"
# read file contents
fh = open(fle, 'r')
content = fh.readlines()

# The dictionary to hold the structure
structure = {}
# reference to structure that we will use in the loop
cur = structure

# loop through file lines
for line in content:

    # Match our starting def line ( def ___ { )
    st = re.match(r'\s*Def\s([^{\s]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE)
    if st:
        cur[st.group(1)] = {}
        cur = cur[st.group(1)]

    # Match the close of a block ( } )
    ed = re.match(r'\s*}\s*', line)
    if ed:
        # ??? How do I tell it to go up one dict level??
        None

    # If its neither, add to current level of array
    # Don't mind the inefficiency here, I'll be improving it later
    if not st and not ed and not re.match(r'\s*{\s*$', line) and not re.match(r'\s*$', line):
        # Not implemented yet
        None

print(structure)
```

Output of the above sample code at the moment is something like

```
mydict = {
    "myitem" : {
        "aSubItem" : {
            "anotherSubItem" : {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If any more information is needed, am happy to provide :)

(and yes, I know I could probably use a parser... but I've had absolutely no luck with any of them at all... besides, writing stuff from scratch is a good practice exercise xD)

Comment: The "example file" is correct? I would expect to have a "def" before myitem.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to put the values "abc", "hi!" or "hows you?" in a dictionary.

Comment: would probably use a list in the actual code, am mainly trying to work out how to move up a dictionary in a loop (as per question) :) .. thanks for noting that though.

Comment: Consider writing a recursive parser.  Whenever it hits a new def block, it assembles the contents and returns a dict.  Inner def blocks are handled by recursively calling the parser and injecting its return values into the outer dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, the children do not automatically have references to their parents, so you can't just "go back."

You need to either explicitly give them those references with a special key like `__parent` or something that will not be duplicated by actual keys, or keep a separate list that will act as a "stack" and keep track of your current path in the tree, appending new levels as you go and `pop`ing them to go back to the parent.

`curLevel = ['myitem']['aSubItem']` is almost there but doesn't work, just use one list `curLevel = ['myitem', 'aSubItem']` and `append` and `pop` as you go.

Depending on your needs, either keep references to the dictionaries in the list, or keep the keys in there and then walk up from the base object using the keys.

Comment: ok, how would I keep track?
Its easy enough to have a list or a string, but I don't know how to 'append' that onto the end of the dictionary call...

Unless you mean have like:
`stack = [structure, structure['myitem'], structure['myitem']['aSubItem'] ]`
and then grab the last item in the list???

Comment: I'm trying that append/pop method saving a reference to the array in each level... seems to be working so far. thanks :)